# Is this result on an unconstrained inverse quadratic programming problem new or known already?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, inverse-problems, quadratic-programming

Is this problem and solution actually new, or has someone done this earlier?

The details can be found in the preprint: [arxiv:1701.01477](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01477).

Let us consider a direct quadratic programming problem:

$$
\min_{\mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x^T}\mathbf{G}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{c^Tx} \\
\text{subject to}\;\mathbf{Ax}\le\mathbf{b}\tag 1
$$
**Problem formulation**

Suppose that in problem $(1)$ neither parameters $(\mathbf{G},\mathbf{c})$, no precise solution $\mathbf{x}_0$, nor minimal value of the target function $f(\mathbf{x}_0)$ corresponding thereto are known. However, the pairs of values $(\mathbf{x}_i,y_i)$ lying in the neighborhoods of $\mathbf{x}_0$ and $f(\mathbf{x}_0)$ are known, so that if the $(\mathbf{G},\mathbf{c})$ were known, then the following equalities would be approximately (or even precisely) valid:

$$
y_i\approx\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^\mathbf{T}_i\mathbf{G}\mathbf{x}_i+\mathbf{c^Tx}_i\tag 2
$$

Then let us formulate the problem being inverse with respect to $(1)$ as a search for the unknown values $(\mathbf{G},\mathbf{c})$, basing on the approximate (or precise) estimates of $\mathbf{x}_0$ and $f(\mathbf{x}_0)$ in the form of the pairs of values $(\mathbf{x}_i,y_i)$, as follows:

$$
\min_{\mathbf{G},\mathbf{c}}\Phi(\mathbf{G},\mathbf{c})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^\mathbf{T}_i\mathbf{G}\mathbf{x}_i+\mathbf{c^Tx}_i-y_i\right)^2\tag 3
$$

**Solution**

Let us introduce a constant multiplier to $(3)$ so that as if both parts of equalities $(2)$ were multiplied by 2:

$$
\min_{\mathbf{G},\mathbf{c}}\Phi(\mathbf{G},\mathbf{c})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\mathbf{x}^\mathbf{T}_i\mathbf{G}\mathbf{x}_i+2\mathbf{c^Tx}_i-2y_i\right)^2\tag 4
$$

Then let us substitute variables as follows:

$$
\mathbf{\hat{x}}_i=\left[1,\mathbf{x}^\mathbf{T}_i\right]^\mathbf{T}, \text{where}\;\hat{x}_{0i}=1\text{,}\;\hat{x}_{li}=x_{li}\text{,}\;\forall{l}=1,\ldots,m\text{,}\;\forall{i}=1,\ldots,N\tag 5
$$
$$
\mathbf{W}=\begin{pmatrix}w_{00}&\mathbf{c}^\mathbf{T}\\\mathbf{c}&\mathbf{G}\end{pmatrix}^\mathbf{T}, \text{where}\;w_{p0}=w_{0p}=c_p\text{,}\;w_{pr}=g_{pr}\text{,}\;\forall{p}=1,\ldots,m\text{,}\;\forall{r}=1,\ldots,m\tag 6
$$

After that we derive formulation $(4)$ in the simplified notation:

$$
\min_{\mathbf{W}}Q(\mathbf{W})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\mathbf{\hat{x}}^\mathbf{T}_i\mathbf{W}\mathbf{\hat{x}}_i-2y_i\right)^2\tag 7
$$

Let us differentiate the function $Q(\mathbf{W})$ with respect to $\mathbf{W}$, equalize the result to zero and regroup multipliers:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{l=0}^m\sum_{t=0}^Z\hat{x}_{li}w_{lt}\hat{x}_{ti}\hat{x}_{pi}\hat{x}_{ri}=2\sum_{i=1}^Ny_i\hat{x}_{pi}\hat{x}_{ri}\text{,}\;\forall{p}=0,\ldots,m\text{,}\;\forall{r}=0,\ldots,m\tag 8
$$

According $(8)$ one can find $\mathbf{W}$ solving next linear system:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\left(\mathbf{vec}\left(\mathbf{\hat{X}D_{\hat{x}}}_0\left(\mathbf{\hat{X}D_{\hat{x}}}_0\right)^\mathbf{T}\right)\right)^\mathbf{T}\\
\ldots\\
\left(\mathbf{vec}\left(\mathbf{\hat{X}D_{\hat{x}}}_p\left(\mathbf{\hat{X}D_{\hat{x}}}_r\right)^\mathbf{T}\right)\right)^\mathbf{T}\\
\ldots\\
\left(\mathbf{vec}\left(\mathbf{\hat{X}D_{\hat{x}}}_m\left(\mathbf{\hat{X}D_{\hat{x}}}_m\right)^\mathbf{T}\right)\right)^\mathbf{T}
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{vec}\mathbf{W}=\mathbf{vec}\left(2\mathbf{\hat{X}D_{y}\hat{X}^T}\right)\text{,}\\
\text{where}\;\mathbf{\hat{X}}=\left[\hat{x}_{pi}\right]_{(m+1)\times N}\text{,}\;\mathbf{D_{\hat{x}}}_p=\mathbf{diag}\left(\hat{x}_{p1},\hat{x}_{p2},\ldots,\hat{x}_{pi},\ldots,\hat{x}_{pN}\right)\text{,}\;\forall{p}=0,\ldots,m\text{;}\;\\
\mathbf{D_{\hat{x}}}_r=\mathbf{diag}\left(\hat{x}_{r1},\hat{x}_{r2},\ldots,\hat{x}_{ri},\ldots,\hat{x}_{rN}\right)\text{,}\;\forall{r}=0,\ldots,m\text{;}\;\\
\mathbf{D_{y}}=\mathbf{diag}\left(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_i,\ldots,y_N\right)
\tag 9
$$

**Updated**

I think I must add arguments according comments to my question.

1. Although, the problem is according to least square method, but it is like nobody found symbolic solution $(9)$ for problem $(7)$ early.
2. Obviously, the solution $(9)$ is global.
3. One can introduce linear constraints simply, for example, by filtering pairs $(\mathbf{x}_i,y_i)$.
4. According previous item one can reconstruct direct QPP with linear constraints.
5. One can use solution $(9)$ for quadric surface fitting.
6. One can reform problem $(7)$ and solution $(9)$ in bilinear form, and so using this in pattern recognition.
7. For ill-conditioned linear systems there are well-know methods such as Tikhonov regularization, pseudoinversion, preconditioning.
8. Preprint contains well-posed and ill-posed problem examples with using Moor-Penrose pseudoinverse.

Comment: As far as I remember, question like "could you check my paper" are not on-topic here. Since you question is a bit different: I, for one, haven't seen such results (do you have some applications in mind?) but i suggest, that you submit your work to an appropriate journal, to get your question answered.

Comment: I can not found such results.

Comment: Editor of AML  said: We have not interest in optimization. Co-editor of ORL said (without arguments): I have not interest in result your paper.

Comment: It is not well phrased as a reference request, but it is in that spirit.  If the poster will add where he searched and did not find the result (so that we see he did some of the work), I am willing to edit and phrase it more properly for this forum.  Gerhard "More Like 'Check Our Memory'" Paseman, 2017.03.17.

Comment: I think those statements of the editors are coming from the "immediate visual impression" that the paper makes --- if you compare it to what published papers in those venues "look like" (literally), and use that as a guideline, it may help getting it reviewed (unfortunately, these types of biases are really hard to avoid it seems!)

Comment: Preprint on arxiv contains references.

Comment: Oh, I see, that's bad (and sheds not the best light onto these journals). My suggestion would be to ask one of the authors of the more recent papers you cited (and maybe they would have a tip on where to submit or how to rewrite).

Comment: Looks like some kind of "brute-force calculus". You might want to transfer this to stackexchange instead.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://mathoverflow.net/q/264897/37212, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2189488/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you solve does not have anything to do with minimizing a quadratic function with linear constraints. You can see this as $Ax\leq b$ plays no role in your analysis. Your problem is a standard linear least squares on function $f$. Note that each unknown $c_j$ depends linearly on the data $x_j$ while the unknown $G_{ij}$ also depends linearly on the data $x_ix_j$. You can solve this problem with textbook linear least squares. No wonder you were able to find closed formula solutions.

I'm sorry but I don't believe there is anything publishable here.

Also, I agree with Suvrit that your paper is not visually adequate.

Finally, your problem statement starts interesting: assume you know a solution $x_0$ (and $f(x_0)$) to your minimization problem. Can you recover $G$ and $c$? this seems not well posed, but maybe you can ask what else you need to know to be able to recover $G$ and $c$.

Comment: I think I found counterarguments. And I list them in update of my question.